# display sql query to create django model object

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps

im learning django 1.8.x. In older django(1.4) we can view sql query like

```
"Begin; 
create table "article_article" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 ...
 ...
); 
COMMIT"
```

for creating model object of an APP called article by running :-

```
python manage.py sql <appname>
```

is there a way so that i can view sql query used to create model objects for that app in Django 1.8.9 ?
cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the SQL per migration now. So assuming it's the first sync (i.e. syncdb in older Django):

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate <appname> 0001
```